# Godot: 2D Raycast is going opposite directions

Tags: 2d, raycasting, godot, topdown

Just started learning Godot and am having trouble with 2D Raycasts going left instead of right or right instead of left.

So I've got a basic top down 2D game with a raycast on the player. Facing up and down works perfectly fine, it's just left and right that are causing headaches. The code looks fine, so that's why I'm here

```
onready var rayCast = get_node("RayCast2D")

func _physics_process(delta):

    vel = Vector2()

    # inputs
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_up"):
        vel.y -= 1
        facingDir = Vector2(0, -1)
    
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_down"):
        vel.y += 1
        facingDir = Vector2(0, 1)
    
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_left"):
        vel.x -= 1
        facingDir = Vector2(1, 0)
    
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_right"):
        vel.x += 1
        facingDir = Vector2(-1, 0)
    

    vel = vel.normalized()

    move_and_slide(vel * moveSpeed)

    manage_animations()

func manage_animations ():

    if vel.x > 0:
        play_animation("MoveRight")
    elif vel.x < 0:
        play_animation("MoveLeft")
    elif vel.y < 0:
        play_animation("MoveUp")
    elif vel.y > 0:
        play_animation("MoveDown")
    elif facingDir.x == -1:
        play_animation("IdleRight")
    elif facingDir.x == 1:
        play_animation("IdleLeft")
    elif facingDir.y == -1:
        play_animation("IdleUp")
    elif facingDir.y == 1:
        play_animation("IdleDown")

func _process(delta):

    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("interract"):
        try_interact()

func try_interact():

    rayCast.cast_to = facingDir * interactDist

    if rayCast.is_colliding():
        if rayCast.get_collider() is KinematicBody2D:
            rayCast.get_collider().take_damage(damage)
        elif rayCast.get_collider().has_method("on_interact"):
            rayCast.get_collider().on_interact(self)
```

I've tried changing the Vector2 x and y variables in the move left and right and while that works, the walking is all messed up then.

Any ideas?

Comment: if Input.is_action_pressed("move_left"):
        vel.x -= 1
        facingDir = Vector2(1, 0) , I think facingDir should be vector(-1,0)  on left

Comment: You know, it's times like this that make me wonder how I am still alive. It was as simple as changing that (which I did try) but then I also needed to change it in the animation function to fix the walking... Yeah. Thanks for the help